# Drop down selection not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs. my dropdown generated successfully but drop down default selection is not working.

See here is my code example :

```
selectedindustry1 = 2

<select class="form-control"  name="industry_1" id="industry_1" ng-model="selectedindustry1" ng-options="industry1.industry_name for industry1 in industrylist track by industry1.industry_id">
                   <option value="">Select industry</option>
</select>
```

Why it happen..? Any idea please let me know..

Comment: are you binding `selectedindustry1` to `$scope` ?

Comment: Yes it is in my js file

Comment: Are you using it like `$scope.selectedindustry1 = 2` ?

Comment: Yes see $scope.selectedindustry1 = $scope.companyprofiledetail.industry_1;

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select ng-init="limit = '10'" ng-change="getPagination()" ng-model="limit"
         style="margin-left: 15px; width: 86px;"  dropdown-toggle>
     <option>10</option>
     <option>20</option>
     <option>50</option>
     <option>100</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: An explanation is always better.